# How To Show Button When Keyboard Is Visible

Tags: uitextview, uibarbuttonitem, uikeyboard

I am using a UITextView to capture multiple lines of text.  I have added a UIBarButtonItem to a Navigation Item on a Navigation Bar that hides the keyboard.

I only want this UIBarButtonItem button to appear when the keyboard is visible.  Is there a way to detect when the keyboard is visible and show a button when it is?

Answer (score 2):

Use following methods:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:self.view.window]; 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:self.view.window];
```

then you can show hide button:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif
{
      // code for show hide button
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notif
{
   // code for show hide button
}
```